# How to add content to registration form? Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, registration

just trying to figure out how I would go about adding content to the account registration form for one of our Magento 2.2 stores. I see the PHTML file located in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml but I am not sure where I need to copy this to make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy register.phtml file from below path

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

to below path

```
app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Customer\templates\form\register.phtml
```

Now you can edit theme file and check your custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need create  child_theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml 
End edit it.
After edit , go to admin panel , content- theme - configuration and just apply it for needed store/store view.